How do I close all applications before quitting awesomewm?
I'd like to write a function that closes all open applications before quitting.
This is to make sure I haven't forgotten to save a modified file.
If I use the Super+Shift+q shortcut, awesome forces all applications to close and I lose any unsaved changes.
Here's what I was able to do:
awful.spawn.easy_async('/home/fabrice/.config/rofi/rofi-query.sh "Eteindre ? "',
                       function(_, _, _, exitcode)
                          if exitcode == 0 then
                             for _, c in ipairs(client.get()) do
                                c:kill()
                             end
                          end
                          -- Wait for all windows to close
                          -- Then exit AwesomeWM
                       end)

What I can't do is wait until all the windows are closed before leaving.
In fact, if a modified file has not been saved, the application asks me
if I want to save it before closing the application.
Only after I've answered all the applications for unsaved files would I want to quit awesome.
I tried to handle the "unmanage" signal (because it is the signal that is emitted when a window is closed) like this:
client.connect_signal("unmanage",
                      function ()
                         if client.instances() == 0 then
                            awesome.quit()
                         end
                      end)

but I'm not leaving awesome.
What I understand is that when the unmanage signal is processed, there is always a window open.
Is there a signal that is called after all the windows are closed?
Or is there another way to close all windows and then exit awesome?

I found the solution :
awful.spawn.easy_async('/home/fabrice/.config/rofi/rofi-query.sh "Eteindre ?"',
                       function(_, _, _, exitcode)
                          if exitcode == 0 then
                             local nb = 0
                             for _, c in ipairs(client.get()) do
                                nb = nb + 1
                             end
                             if nb == 0 then
                                awesome.quit()
                             else
                                client.connect_signal("unmanage",
                                                      function ()
                                                         local nb = 0
                                                         for _, c in ipairs(client.get()) do
                                                            nb = nb + 1
                                                         end
                                                         if nb == 0 then
                                                            awesome.quit()
                                                         end
                                                      end)
                                for _, c in ipairs(client.get()) do
                                   c:kill()
                                end
                             end
                          end
                       end)

The mistake I was making was to use client.instances() to get the number of open windows.
Here's how it works:
If no window is open then I immediately quit awesome.
Otherwise, I define a function to handle the signal (unmanage) that is emitted when windows are closed, and then request that all windows be closed.
In the unmanage signal function, I count the number of windows still open and when no window is open, I quit awesome.
